# Frequency map by country

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, maps

I am trying to make a world map with some specific frequency data for some countries. I have tried to use plotly (below), but the base map is not available, and it won't let me load a new one I found.

The map I need is a color scale (intensity) for the countries with presence of this variable.

These are the data and the code with which I have tried to plot the map:

```
database = px.data.gapminder()

d = {'Australia':[3],
'Brazil' :[2],
'Canada':[6],
'Chile':[3],
'Denmark':[1],
'France':[16],
'Germany':[3],
'Israel':[1]}


data = pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index()
data.columns=['country', 'count']

df=pd.merge(database, yourdata, how='left', on='country')

url = (
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/examples/data"
)

fig = px.choropleth(df, locations="country",
                    locationmode='ISO-3',
                    geojson = f"{url}/world-countries.json",
                    color="count")
```

I keep getting the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why it is not displayed is because the location mode and the target column are incorrectly specified. If the location mode is 'iso_3', then for this data, the location would be 'iso_alpha'. Also, if the location mode is 'country names', then the location would be 'country'. Since there are many data presented, we extracted by year and changed the merging method.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Australia':[3],
'Brazil' :[2],
'Canada':[6],
'Chile':[3],
'Denmark':[1],
'France':[16],
'Germany':[3],
'Israel':[1]}


data = pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index()
data.columns=['country', 'count']

import plotly.express as px

database = px.data.gapminder().query('year == 2007')

df = pd.merge(database, data, how='inner', on='country')
url = (
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/examples/data"
)

fig = px.choropleth(df,
                    locations="country",#"iso_alpha",
                    locationmode="country names",#"ISO-3",
                    geojson = f"{url}/world-countries.json",
                    color="count"
                   )

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, it still doesn't work for me. I have used your code, and it still doesn't work. I get the same error regarding the base map:  Javascript Error: unexpected error while fetching topojson file at https://cdn.plot.y/world_110m

Comment: Is the version currently in use up-to-date? The latest is 5.9.0.

Comment: I just update the plotly version, and the error is the same :(

Comment: Is it an environmental issue? Have you tried running my code, I have expanded it to [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13dkZo0PJ7hAjowQFUcT6ZJkLRUv-E4sl?usp=sharing) so please check my code and data.